# Iterate through directories, subdirectories, to get files with specialized ext. , copy in new directory

Tags: python, loops, subdirectory

I have a question and I went all the other topics through with similar problems but I didn't get my solved.

I have a folder where two subfolders are. Inside of them are a lot of files, but I need just files with extension `.trl`. I need to copy them and save them in a new folder that is already created.
My code don't give me an error but I don't see any result. What I'm doing wrong?

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch

directory = "/home/.../test_daten"
ext = ('.trl')
dest_dir = "/home/.../test_korpus"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for extension in ext:
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, extension+'.trl'):
            source = (os.path.join(root, filename))
            shutil.copy2(source, dest_dir)
```

Comment: `fnmatch.filter(files, extension+'.trl'):` ---where is `extension` defined? i'd prefer `if filename.endswith('.trl')`

Comment: What do you think *for extension in ext* is going to do? You have defined *ext = ('.trl')* The parentheses are redundant so what you have is a string meaning that when you iterate over it you'll get one letter at a time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.walk()` and find all files. Then use `endswith()` to find the files ending with `.trl`.
Sample code:

```py
import os, shutil;

directory = "/home/.../test_daten";
dest_dir = "/home/.../test_korpus";

filelist = [];

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file));

for trlFile in filelist:
    if trlFile.endswith(".trl"):
        shutil.copy(trlFile, dest_dir);
```

Comment: the OP is using `os.walk` in the quetion. so why emphasize?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is `fnmatch.filter(files, extension+'.trl')`. You have `extension` from `for extension in ext:` which will loop though the variable `ext` and give you a letter from it each time. `Your extension+'.trl` will be `..trl, t.trl, l.trl`

```py
import os
import shutil

directory = "/home/.../test_daten"
dest_dir = "/home/.../test_korpus"

for root, _, files in os.walk(directory): #Get the root, files
    for x in files:
        if x.endswith('.trl'): #Check the extension
            shutil.copy2(f'{root}/{x}', dest_dir)
```

Comment: What do you think *files.endswith* is going to do apart from raise an exception? Your f-string construction is completely wrong notwithstanding you should always use os.path.join for this kind of thing

Comment: My bad, I fixed it. It supposed to loop though the files.

Comment: OP wants to use copy2 Why have you changed to copyfile? Their behaviours are potentially different

Comment: @ArthurKing I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch

source = "/home/.../test_daten"
ext = '*.trl'
target = "/home/.../test_korpus"

for root, _, files in os.walk(source):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, ext):
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root, filename), target)
```